# Keep window open when execute python script

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm trying to asktoopenfile, get path and open it to make report. My code as below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys
import os
import openpyxl as xl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
        
def get_file():
    global file_abc
    file_abc = filedialog.asktoopenfilename(title = "Select A File",filetypes=(("xlsx","*xlsx),("All Files,"*.*)))
    
window = tk.TK()
window.title("Get File")
window.geometry('1000x1000')
    
button1 = tk.Button(window,text="File_ABC",command=get_file,bg='#6eb5ff',fg'white',width=100).pack()
button2 = tk.Button(window,text="Run",command=window.destroy,bg='#b28dff',fg'white',width=100).pack()
window.mainloop()

print(file_abc)
abc = pd.read_excel("r'" and file_abc,engine="openpyxl")
```

But problem is I have to use `window destroy` to run `print` and `read_excel` scripts. I want to ask is there another way to keep window open when execute scripts.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Why don't you put the two lines after `mainloop()` inside `get_file()`?

Comment: Also there are many typo errors.

Comment: @acw1668 thank for your respond, I'm not a coder and I just want find a way to process data instead of VBA. 

So you mean that I have to do something like that:
`def get_file():
    global file_abc
    file_abc = filedialog.asktoopenfilename(title = "Select A File",filetypes=(("xlsx","*xlsx),("All Files,"*.*)))
print(file_abc)
abc = pd.read_excel("r'" and file_abc,engine="openpyxl")`

Comment: Basically yes.  But I think you need to declare `abc` as global as well, otherwise it cannot be accessed outside the function.  But first thing is that you need to fix those typo errors first.

Comment: @acw1668 Yep, it's just a sample code. I tried to fix my code as your suggestion but I still have to close Tk window to run code.

Comment: Is the *code* something else other than the two lines?  If yes, then you need to move *those code* inside `get_file()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Try This

Use the excel commands in a different thread. This might help.

```py
import threading

def your_excel_function(word):
    print(word)

x = threading.Thread(target=your_excel_function, args=("Hello World"))
x.start()
```

Even better, run it as a background daemon. A daemon is a background process

```py
import threading

def your_excel_function(word):
    print(word)

x = threading.Thread(target=your_excel_function, args=("Hello World"), daemon=True)
x.start()
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, can use explain more about it or use my case to make code.?